# How to alter the table to add foreign key constraint referencing primary key of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

When I try to alter the table to add the foreign constraint, it is throwing the below error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_ManagerId". The conflict occurred in database "MX_STAG", table "dbo.Sales_US_User", column 'ID'.

I tried the below queries,none of them have worked.

```
ALTER TABLE SALES_US_USER
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ManagerId
        FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES SALES_US_USER(id);

ALTER TABLE SALES_US_USER 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES SALES_US_USER(id);
```

Please help

Comment: Can you please show us the **structure** of your table in question? Preferably the DDL statement you used to create it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Sales_MX_User (
 ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
 Username VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 ManagerID VARCHAR(20);

Comment: I need to add foreign key constraint on managerId referencing ID of same table, without dropping/recreating the table.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the DDL right.  That error is telling you that you have a row with a ManagerId that does not map to an Id.  EG

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists sales_us_manager
go
create table sales_us_user(Id int primary key, ManagerId int)


insert into sales_us_user(id,managerId) values (1,2)


ALTER TABLE SALES_US_USER
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ManagerId
        FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES SALES_US_USER(id);

--Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
--The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_ManagerId". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.sales_us_user", column 'Id'.

select *
from SALES_US_USER
where ManagerId not in 
  (select id from SALES_US_USER )
```

Comment: please let me know if there are any alternative ways to achieve this. I do not want to drop and re-create.

Comment: Find and update the rows with an an invalid ManagerId, or create the FK with NOCHECK to allow existing rows to violate the constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete both table data before updated database with your new migration. One of the common mistakes that you add a FK (foreign key) from table to another while any on these table contains data. The constraint happens because the FK can't be null and while you are adding the new migration the database find that the new column that will be created will be null so, delete the data in both tables first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after finding and updating the rows with an an invalid ManagerId, and then created the constraint.